# How to allow a Google Chrome plugin to access files as webpages

Tags: google-chrome, security, plugins

I made a webpage that I can view in two ways.

1. If I run it on a local webserver, the beginning of the address starts with 127.0.0.1
2. Without a webserver, I can load the file in the browser and the address will start with file:///

I have a chrome plugin that I'm trying to use with this webpage. It doesn't work when the page is accessed in the second way.

I read that this can be fixed by manually changing a setting to allow the plugin to still function on webpages that are files. However the description of the process was unclear and I was not able to get it to work.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to `chrome://extensions/`

[image]

Click on that arrow mark (it's kinda small, and not so clear) to the left of the plugin you want to allow and then check the

> Allow access to file URLS

You are good