# Can an app or extension open files on system with permission "<all_urls>"?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I thought Chrome apps were sandboxed, but I see that you can allow permissions for `file://` urls, and there's a special matching pattern:

> <all_urls>     Matches any URL that uses a permitted scheme. (See the beginning of this section for the list of permitted schemes.)

Are the file urls restricted to within the sandbox or can it really go anywhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can access the entire filesystem (subject to the permissions of the user account running Chrome). **However**, the user must explicitly activate access to `file:` URLs by checking the "Allow access to file URLs" box by your extension's listing in `chrome://extensions`. Your extension must satisfy both requirements:

1. include the permission in the manifest (either a particular `file://...` match pattern or `<all_urls>`), and
2. have the "Allow access to file URLs" box checked by the user.

See also [How to allow a Google Chrome plugin to access files as webpages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921436/710446).

Comment: Thank you, I thought I could only access things outside the sandbox via an DOM object `<input type="file"...>` where the user chooses a file. This helps.

Comment: I just found out that despite Google's documentation claiming otherwise, your answer has one small thing incorrect. Using a matching pattern other than `"<all_urls>"` will never show the checkbox. For example, `"*://*/*"` does not work. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17183785/857025

Comment: @DonRhummy It may have been different two years ago, but [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) currently says "If the scheme is `*`, then it matches either `http` or `https`, and **not** `file`, or `ftp`."