# How do I get the checkbox "Allow access to file URLs" to show up next to my app? I have file write permissions in manifest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

### **More Info/Update**

I packaged and installed google's own sample app showing filesystem access and it also does **not** show the checkbox!

You can find it here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/filesystem-access

**Original Post**

I have the permission asking for filesystem.write ability in my manifest but on the `chrome://extensions` page, the check box doesn't show up. And when I click "permissions" next to my app's icon, it only shows:

> "Write to files that you have opened in the application"

What am I doing wrong? (This is a hosted app)

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Hello World",
    "description": "A test application",
    "version": "2.0.3.92",
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "update_url": "http://mywebsite.com/updates/helloworld.xml",
    "icons": 
    {
        "16": "icon_16.png",
        "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "app": 
    {
        "background": 
        {
            "scripts": 
            [
                "utils.js",
                "fs.js",
                "main.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    "permissions": 
    [
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "fullscreen",
        {
            "fileSystem": 
            [
                "write"
            ]
        },
        "background",
        "http://*/",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can do that with an extension? Isn't that feature only for packaged apps?

Comment: my app is a packaged app. it's in a crx and is delivered via a hosted url.

Comment: @JudeOsborn See my answer below, I got it to work with a special permission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get this to work you need either:

```
permissions: [ "<all_urls>" ]
```

or a scheme starting with `file:///`.

If you try `*://*/*` that will **not** work as it only represents http or https

Comment: Don, could you file a bug for this at crbug.com?

Comment: This behaviour is clearly documented, and therefore not a bug: "If the scheme is `*`, then it matches either `http` or `https`."

Comment: @RobW thanks. I thought in the context of chrome apps that * also stood for the file scheme. I'll reflect that I'm my answer

Comment: This likely changed sometime in the last 6 years, but I’m seeing on Chrome 77 that a simple extension with no permissions other than "activeTab" will get the “Allow access to file URLs” option in it’s chrome://extensions settings page.