# Cannot load Chrome extension for local html files (file:/// schema)

Tags: file, google-chrome-extension, schema, content-script

I found this very useful answer for my question but it is not working for me:
[Can an app or extension open files on system with permission "<all_urls>"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155916/can-an-app-or-extension-open-files-on-system-with-permission-all-urls)

Here is a part of my manifest.json:

```
...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [<all_urls>], // tried also "file:///*"
...
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
...
```

And also I got my **"Allow access to file URLs"** box checked in the extensnions:// tab.

Still, the Content script tab in the Developer tools is empty when I open a local html file:///

Extension is loaded for http:// urls, no probs.

Anybody has any idea if there is something more or am I missing something?

Comment: `<all_urls>` in `matches` should be in quotes.  But I assume you've actually done that and it's just a copy/paste error here, because Chrome would complain if you had that in your manifest.

Comment: It should load with `"<all_urls>"` + that checkbox unless you indeed have the above typo.

Answer (score 0):

@Teepeemm and @wOxxOm you are right to point the ***missing quotes***. My JSON is weak.

But interestingly Chrome didn't complain when reloading the extension until I restarted Chrome. Also it seems it kept the old version loaded and this fooled me that  is working. 
So *even Chrome needs to be restarted sometimes to work properly* :)

PS. I did try a few different patterns, so yes I clicked the reload button many times. But I notice there is a few seconds lag of the reloading - I use Browserify and my background.js is 580 000 lines.

Comment: When I try to reload an extension with that in my manifest, Chrome tells me: "Manifest is not valid JSON. Line: 26, column: 20, Unexpected token."  Are you sure you were hitting "Reload" with that manifest?