# Allow Chrome extension to run on a local file (i.e. a downloaded PDF)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way I can allow my extension to run on a local PDF? I have a content script that invokes a remote database insertion of some text on a webpage, but I can't find a way to use it on a local file as well.

Comment: [How to allow a Google Chrome plugin to access files as webpages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8921492) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow a Google Chrome plugin to access files as webpages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921436/how-to-allow-a-google-chrome-plugin-to-access-files-as-webpages)